# Compare two strings of objects in a Vector

Tags: java

I had to code my own `compareTo()`-Method for a lexical order for Objects called `Beer`, which compares the `Beer` by beer type and beer name.

So here is my `compareTo` Method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Beer b) {
    String compareBeer1 = this.getBeerType() + this.getbName();
    String compareBeer2 = b.getBeerType() + b.getbName();
    for(int i = 0; i < compareBeer1.length(); i++) {
        if(compareBeer1.charAt(i) > compareBeer2.charAt(i)) {
            return compareBeer1.charAt(i) - compareBeer2.charAt(i);
        } else if(compareBeer1.equals(compareBeer2)) {
            return 0;
        } else if((compareBeer1.charAt(i) == compareBeer2.charAt(i)) && (compareBeer1.length() - compareBeer2.length()) > 0){
            return compareBeer1.length() - compareBeer2.length();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So far so good, my problem here is now, that I have a `Vector<Beer> filteredBeer`, which I have to sort also in lexical order. So for this, my code is:

```
Collections.sort(filteredBeer, new Comparator<Beer>() {
        public int compare(Beer beer1, Beer beer2) {
            return beer1.compareTo(beer2);
        }
    });
```

Still, I don't get the results I wish for, it doesn't compare the whole `Vector` and sorts it. It does it only for the first two elements and that's it.

Can anyone help out? Or tell me, where my error here is?

Comment: Could you post a couple Beer examples, so that I can try out your code?

Comment: for example: 
Beer 1: Type = malt Name = Pipers Strong Beer -> String: maltPipers Strong Beer
Beer 2: Type = malt Name = Pipers Soft Beer -> String: maltPipers Soft Beer
Beer 3: Type = malt Name = Pipers 1957 Beer -> String: maltPipers 1957 Beer
Beer 4: Type = malt Name = Pipers Soft Beer for Strong Men -> String: maltPipers Soft Beer for Strong Men

sorry for the format. It is on purpose, that the type and the name are concatted together without a whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method is pretty strange.
What you should need is only this

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Beer b) {
    final var compareBeer1 = getBeerType().trim() + getName().trim();
    final var compareBeer2 = b.getBeerType().trim() + b.getName().trim();
    return compareBeer1.compareTo(compareBeer2);
}
```

*Note that it can be enhanced for null-checks and other nice things.*
Your beers will be sorted in ascending alphabetical order by type and name.
Tested with

```
final List<Beer> beers = new ArrayList<>();
beers.add(new Beer("tre", "nome2"));
beers.add(new Beer("due", "snome2"));
beers.add(new Beer("uno", "nome1"));
beers.add(new Beer("uno", "nome5"));
beers.add(new Beer("uno", "nome4"));
beers.add(new Beer("uno", "nome2"));
beers.add(new Beer("due", "nome1"));

Collections.sort(beers, Beer::compareTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo depends on Beer's equals() method.
looks like the equals() methods of Beer was not overridden correctly (or not overridden at all?) which in this case it rely on the Object's implementation...

Comment: since I compare strings in the "compareTo"-method, it shouldn't be a concern. I use strings in the compareTo-Method, that's where I also use the equals() method for strings.